# Possible to limit the scope of Directory.Build.Props to a single Visual Studio Solution?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a Visual Studio solution with over 100 projects in it. I want to apply certain settings to all projects, so I used a Directory.Build.Props file and it works great. However, after reading the documentation I just realized that all of the solutions in the sub directories will use those settings too, but I don't want to affect those solutions since I don't maintain them. Is there a way to limit the scope of a Directory.Build.Props file to the current directory, or a particular solution? (Perhaps you can customize the name of the Props file and import it for a particular solution?)

For example, consider a directory structure organized as such:

```
/code/MySolutionFile.sln
/code/Project001/
/code/Project002/
/code/Project003/
...
/code/Project100/

/code/OtherStuff/OtherStuff.sln
/code/OtherStuff/ProjectA
/code/OtherStuff/ProjectB
/code/OtherStuff/[lots of other solutions somewhere in this directory tree]
```

I have put my `Directory.Build.Props` file in the `/code` directory because I would like to define settings for all projects in `/code/MySolutionFile.sln`. But I don't want to affect any of the other solutions in subdirectories of the `/code` folder.

If all else fails I think I could create an empty Directory.Build.Props file and drop it in every directory that contains a solution file except for the one I want mine to apply to. (But this feels like a last resort.)

Comment: The `Directory.Build.Props` file will affect `xxx.sln` of the current root directory and search down on any `xxx.proj` files of the sub folder. It is designed by that. You can see its [search scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#search-scope).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying my Directory.Build.props file in this way accomplishes my goal:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(SolutionFileName) == 'MySolution.sln'">
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

This works by setting the `PropertyGroup` to conditionally run the rules. (Note the condition could also be applied to specific rules rather than the group.) In this case I was able to use the name of the solution file to limit the scope of this rule to my desired solution without affecting any others.

One caveat though, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=vs-2017) claims that the solution variables are only available when used in the IDE. However, with my limited testing the rules are also correctly applied when I use msbuild from the command line, like this: `msbuild.exe MySolution.sln`

I tested it from both a VS Developer Command Prompt and a regular Windows Command Prompt, and both still read the `$(SolutionFileName)` variable properly.

Answer (score 1):

MSBuild supports `Conditions` on many types of element, including `PropertyGroup` and individual properties. In this case, you don't need the `Choose-When` - you could just put the condition on the `PropertyGroup` or `TreatWarningsAserrors` directly.

Comment: Thanks. I have incorporated your statement into the answer, since it is cleaner than what I had.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to limit the scope of a Directory.Build.Props file to
>   the current directory, or a particular solution? (Perhaps you can
>   customize the name of the Props file and import it for a particular
>   solution?)

The `Directory.Build.Props` will act on the `xxxx.sln` of the current folder which contains many included `xxxx.csproj` files and then also act on the `xxxx.proj` files of all the sub folders. It will go down one step at a time for any `xxx.proj` file which it finds and it is designed by that. You can see the [search scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#search-scope) of it.

Since your workaround works well but it is a bit complex, or you can try my solution if you are willing to:

**Workaround**

Please create a folder called `MyStuff` under the folder **code** and then put **Project001---Project100** into this folder. After that, put your `Directory.Build.Props` file into `MyStuff` folder. With it, the file will affect only **Project001---Project100**.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. Changing the directory structure is too invasive in my case, but I do believe it would work if someone had the option to do it. I did happen to figure out a way to accomplish what I needed which I posted in another answer.